# How to open whatsappcontacts from my web app

Tags: android-intent, web-applications

I'm trying to create a link on my website which opens users' Whatsapp contacts and counts the number of selected contacts they resend the link to.
What [Android intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) would I use?

thanks in advance...

Comment: What Android Intents have you tried so far? What did not work?

Comment: Thanks. Mmmmm, I haven't tried any so far because I'm new to this(android/whatsapp programming)...BUT: I'm a fast learner and have a general broad understanding of the basics. I'd be appreciative if you would graciously walk me through how YOU would do it...Thanks in advance.